# How run export NODE_PATH="/usr/lib/node_modules" in code PHP?

Tags: php, node.js

I use http://mink.behat.org/en/latest/drivers/zombie.html

When I run the file using the command line `php zb.php` I have to run `export NODE_PATH="/usr/lib/node_modules"` first to make it work.

I added `export NODE_PATH="/usr/lib/node_modules"` into file `/root/.bashrc` and now I can run `php zb.php` without the need to run the `export` command first.

But when I run the file `zb.php` via the website, (I mean via `http://localhost/zb.php`) it returns a `500` error.

I think in PHP I can't run `export NODE_PATH="/usr/lib/node_modules"`.

How can I run `export NODE_PATH="/usr/lib/node_modules"` in PHP code? Or what else to do to fix the error?

My code (`zb.php`):

```
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

$driver = new \Behat\Mink\Driver\ZombieDriver(
    new \Behat\Mink\Driver\NodeJS\Server\ZombieServer()
);


$session = new \Behat\Mink\Session($driver);

// start the session
$session->start();

$session->visit('https://www.facebook.com/login/identify?ctx=recover&lwv=100');

/*
echo $session->getStatusCode();
print_r($session->getResponseHeaders());
*/
//$page = $session->getPage();

//$el = $page->findById('pageTitle');

// get tag name:
///print_r($el);
echo $session->getStatusCode();

?>
```

Comment: Which user runs your webserver? You'll need to export the environment variable as that user for it to be readable by it.